# Vagrant VM is running but not showing up in Virtualbox Manager (MacOS)

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, virtualbox

I've recently installed VirtualBox, Vagrant and Chef DK and when I run **kitchen converge** my VM comes up properly provisioned with my cookbook using vagrant and the Virtualbox provider however I am unable to view or manage the vm from the VirtualBox Manager

I can however view see the vm running via kitchen list or vagrant global-status

Upon reviewing where the .vbox is being loaded I can see that its going in the ~/my_cookbook/.kitchen/nameofvm/ folder

When I review the default Machine location set in Virtual box i can see it's located in the /Users//VirtualBox VMs/ folder however it does not appear to be following this attribute

So far i've reinstalled vagrant, VirtualBox and Chef DK

I'm running MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 and only have started having this issue since upgrading to MacOS Sierra.

Anyone have any recommendations or some extra steps that I could take to potentially resolve this issue?

```
    Chef Development Kit Version: 2.1.11
    chef-client version: 13.2.20
    delivery version: master (73ebb72a6c42b3d2ff5370c476be800fee7e5427)
    berks version: 6.3.0
    kitchen version: 1.17.0
    inspec version: 1.33.1

    vboxmanage -v
    5.1.26r117224

    Vagrant 1.9.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an inadvertent mis-feature of a change in kitchen-vagrant, which has since been reverted. ChefDK 2.2 includes this fixed version of kitchen-vagrant and should be released either later today or tomorrow morning. You can also roll back to ChefDK 2.0. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I upgraded to the recent build (not stable) and this fixed the issue! Thank you!

Comment: 2.2 was released about an hour ago so you can move to that if you want to be back on a stable release.